# C++: Using pointers as private member variables without breaking encapsulation?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, encapsulation

I have a class Film that contains an integer pointer Chapitres and the number of elements of that array Count_chapitres.

```
 class film : public video
{
private:
    int* Chapitres;
    unsigned int Count_chapitres;
public:
    film();
    film(int* Chapitres, unsigned int Count_Chapitres, int Duree, string Name, string Filename);
    virtual ~film();
    void setChapitres (int * Chapitres, unsigned int Count_Chapitres);
    int * getChapitres() const;
    unsigned int getCountChapitres() const;
    void printOut (ostream & Display) const;

};
```

**The obvious problem is that giving away the pointer will break encapsulation.**

1) I have tried setting the output of get to const int *, in which simply casting the output back using a *const_cast* reverted the measure back. As the following allowed the Evil pointer to externally change film data:

```
film* file2 = new film(Chaps, 3, 5, "hany", "daher");

    file2->printOut(cout);
    int * Evil = const_cast<int *>(file2->getChapitres());
    *(Evil +1)=9;
    file2->printOut(cout);
```

2) Also even though I put const int * as arguments for my constructor/setter it still takes int * objects as arguments in main making the *const* keyword essentially redundant.

The solution evidently does not lie in pointers to constant values. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Why do you use a pointer in the first place?

Comment: To begin with don't use pointers for "dynamic arrays", use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Secondly, any kind of "getter" will break encapsulation. Model your classes on *behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know that, it is just part of my assignement to do it without vectors in order to highlight this problem. And I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you mean by remodeling the class.

Comment: Why do you store a pointer that is going to be used outside the class? Just because it seems related to what that class is supposed to be defined for?

Comment: Before you head too far down this path, make sure you understand [The Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). And while you're there, learn about the Rules of Five and Zero since they're related.

Comment: @user4581301 I shall look into that. Thank you.

Comment: try: int const * getChapitres();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand that encapsulation is protection as in 'gun safety switch', not as in 'strong cryptography'. You should not worry about possibility of class users doing `const_cast` with the returned `const pointer` anymore than you would worry of them typing something like `#define private public` before including your header class.

In C++ there are unlimited possibilities for deliberately breaking your encapsulation, both with outside behavior or without it. Instead, encapsulation tries to protect users of the class from innocent errors.

In your particular case, you need to const-qualify your getter function and return `const int*`. Alternatively, since you already have trivial getters and setters, you can do away with them and simply declare your members public with the same level of encapsulation.

Comment: Seemes fair enough, I do realize the whole assignement seems weird. But its point was to highlight the difficulties in using pointers. I'll abide by your suggestion then.